# Ошибка при выполнении функции в запросе: "ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть такая функция:

```
function get_avail_addr_list (p_range_id number, p_how_many number) return ref_cursor;
```

Пытаюсь к ней обратиться:

```
select * from table(pkgipplanner.get_avail_addr_list(9191919191919191919, 17));
```

и получаю вот такую ошибку:

> ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Что делаю не так?

Есть аналогичная функция, ее вызываю подобным способом и все нормально. Тело функции увидеть не могу, но аналогичная работающая функция выглядит так:

```
function get_addr_list (
    p_range_id number, p_start_addr number, p_end_addr number) return ref_cursor;
```

---

P.S. К данной функции в пакете идет вот такое описание:

> ```
>    Returns the ref_cursor of available IP addresses from specified IP range
>
>    * param p_range_id - object_id of IP range to select IP addresses from
>
>    * param p_how_many - requires number of IP addresses
>
>    * return ref_cursor {(addr, object_id, parent_id)}
> ```

Comment: Покажите код функции, если он большой оставьте основные части

Comment: А вы уверены что функция точно такая же как и та что работает. например что такое этот ref_cursor ? И какое возвращаемое значение у той функции что работает нормально. подозреваю что ref_cursor это pl/sql курсор в пакете. А table работает с типами, а не pl/sql курсорами

Comment: боюсь без исходников функций и описания ref_cursor сказать ничего нельзя. вполне возможно что надо что то подправить в самой функции

Comment: подправил основной текст - добавил P.S.

Answer (score 3):

Если под `ref_cursor` кроется ссылка на курсор, то вызвать функцию в SQL запросе нельзя. Ссылка на курсор это PL/SQL тип данных, он не известен в SQL контехте.

> работающая функция выглядит так - function get_addr_list (p_range_id number, p_start_addr number, p_end_addr number) return ref_cursor;

Если это действительно так, то некто пренебрёг правилом - называть вещи своими именами.

Например, имя типа данных `ref_cursor` в SQL контехте неверно описывает его суть:

```
create or replace type currow is object (id int, memo varchar2 (64))
/
create or replace type ref_cursor is table of currow
/
create or replace function getcursor (n int, m varchar2) return ref_cursor is
begin 
    return ref_cursor (currow (n, m));
end;
/
create or replace package pkg is
    type ref_cursor is ref cursor; 
    function getcursor (n int, m varchar2) return ref_cursor;
end;
/
create or replace package body pkg is
    function getcursor (n int, m varchar2) return ref_cursor is
        rc ref_cursor;
    begin 
        open rc for select n, m from dual;
        return rc;
    end;
end;
/
```

Обе функции `getcursor` выглядят вроде похоже, но одна работает, другая нет:

```
select * from table (iam.getcursor (1, 'memo'));
 
        ID MEMO                                                            
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
         1 memo                                                            

select * from table (pkg.getcursor (1, 'memo'));

SQL Error: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
```